# An Alternative to Data Attribute in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

i have a webpage where user can select one of different packages to buy from a list. Package details are coming from a database.

> HTML Code

```
<div data-package='2346343' class="retail-package">Cost : 10$</div> 
<div data-package='5465654' class="retail-package">Cost : 20$</div> 
<div data-package='3455675' class="retail-package">Cost : 30$</div>
```

> Jquery Code

```
$('.retail-package').on('click', function() {
   $(this).addClass("selected-package");
   var selectedPackage = $(this).data("package");
});
```

Now above code shows how we(specially i) normally select a particular thing out of a list when clicked, In this procedure, as you can see in HTML Code, i am giving out or showing the `pakcageId` to users i.e. anyone can do a inspect element in a browser and view or even manipulate the `data-package` attribute, for safety i do a server side check of selected data.

> My Question

Is there a way to hide this data exposure, or is there any other cleaner way to accomplish this, because i have seen people using `Angular`, `Webpack` etc able to implement a `list selection` without giving out or showing any data which can be seen by inspect element feature in a browser.

Note : i am sorry if my question is too basic, if this cannot done using jquery what are other technologies which i can use ?

Comment: You can store `pakcageId` in javascript array and in onclick get it. However user can see it but not easily.

Comment: When a client should send an id to the server, there is no way to do it without the risk (or certainess) that an user can manipulate data. You can hide some infos in js incapsulated variables, or in a custom DOM object proprerty, but the client always can knows the value if he wants. By other hand, he can always send data to server totally bypassing the UI

Comment: @LucaRainone .... yes i understand that there is some or the other way a client can find the data but i just wanted to make it hard and my aim of the question was to know the best practice or the technology.

Comment: @GauravKumar if you see the html of facebook or twitter you can catch a lot of id of everything (users, post, comments). There is nothing of bad to expose them if all checks are made by server. 
You can prevent data modification with some tricks like a control string for every input and/or prevent CSRF attack in order to don't accept input without a request of linked UI form.

Comment: @LucaRainone ok will consider that !! thank you so much for clearing the air.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a `Map` where *keys* are arbitrary, auto-incremented identifiers, and *values* are *package numbers*:

```js
const idPackageMap = new Map()

// id generator: whenever you call it, "i" is incremented and returned
const id = (() => {
  let i = 0

  return () => ++i
})()

const addPackage = package =>
  idPackageMap.set(id(), package)

addPackage(2346343)
addPackage(5465654)
addPackage(3455675)

console.log('contents: ', [...idPackageMap.entries()])
console.log('package number for id 2: ', idPackageMap.get(2))
```

Now, when you insert those `<div>` elements you may set the *arbitrary identifier*, and when you need to locate the actual *package number*  is just about using `Map#get`: `idPackageMap.get(1)` (change `1` with any arbitrary identifier).

Comment: I will try to implement this, just can you edit this answer with what will be the HTML side of your answer, Thanks in advance !! and is there any advantage of using angular, react in such scenarios  ?

Comment: @GauravKumar Your HTML is exactly the same as the one in your own question body: just set the arbitrary `id` instead of the package number :D

Comment: @GauravKumar The advantage of using some of these frameworks is you would use *data-binding*, but the core problem is almost the same (you would use the same solution).